# Rails 4 + Turbolinks + JQuery Turbolinks + Coffeescript: Events being fired multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, turbolinks

At first, all the javascript bounded are running pretty well.

However, from the moment I navigate to another page, any event is being fired multiple times. If I refresh the page, everything is back to normal.

In the jquery.turbolink docs, [there is an alert](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks#events-firing-twice-or-more) about binding the document events inside a $(function()) block. However, seems like the coffescript works like this by default. So, what should I do?

This is my environment:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//..app js
//= require turbolinks
```

application.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%= t 'brand' %> </title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= yield :head %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= yield :page_description %>">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<%= yield :page_keywords %>">
  </head>
```

controller.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->    
  $(document).on 'click', '.addition .label i', (e) ->
    console.log ".addition .label i 'click' fired!"
```

The thing is, apparently the javascript file generated by coffeescript IS inside a block by default. Check it out:

controller.js (generated by coffeescript)

```
function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.addition .label i', function(e) {
      console.log(".addition .label i 'click' fired!");
    });
...
```

So, what should I do to use coffeescript +  JQuery Turbolinks properly?
Should I make a different configuration?

Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in controller.js.coffee.

You wrote this:

```
$(document).ready ->    
  $(document).on 'click', '.addition .label i', (e) ->
    console.log ".addition .label i 'click' fired!"
```

But since you're using jQuery Turbolinks, you need to move the event handlers *outside* the $(document).ready function:

```
$(document).ready ->
  # Other code can go here, but not binding event handlers
$(document).on 'click', '.addition .label i', (e) ->
  console.log ".addition .label i 'click' fired!"
```

Take a look at the [jQuery Turbolinks README](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks). It mentions this problem and solution. (Search the readme for "Events firing twice or more.")

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turned out that I've changed the approach completely.

Now, I've got exactly the same environment, but I'm using classes to represent the javascript for each controller. Here is one example:

foo.js.coffee:

```
window.App or= {}

class App.Foo
  constructor: ->
    @$foo_container = $('.foo')
    @bind()

  bind: ->
    console.log 'App.Foo.bind has been fired!'
    @$foo_container.on 'click', '.label i', @foo_clicked

  foo_clicked: (e) =>
    console.log 'App.Foo.foo_clicked has been fired!'
    alert '.label i has been clicked!'

create_foo = ->
  window.app.foo = new App.Foo()
  console.log 'App.Foo has been created!'

$(document).ready create_foo
```

Now, it works like a charm. :)